# Creating separate class names from innerHTML Javascript string

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to create two class values for the same innerHTML element, but adding a space between the two doesn't seem to work.

This is the line I'm trying to figure out.

```
"<tr class=" + 'element-item' + ` ` + name + ">" +
```

Here's the rest of the code for reference. Thanks!

```js
  let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText).feed.entry;

    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let name = data[i]["gsx$_cn6ca"]["$t"];
      let age = data[i]["gsx$_cokwr"]["$t"];
      let email = data[i]["gsx$_cpzh4"]["$t"];

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML +=
        "<tr class=" + 'element-item' + ` ` + name + ">" +
        "<td>" +
        age +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
        email +
        "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
    }
  }
  };

  xmlhttp.open(
  "GET",
  "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1ZIptCxioF5KBj0T76F3lILNvne35EhLhFrdrNccOC8A/od6/public/values?alt=json",
  true
  );
  xmlhttp.send();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-7">

      <!-- Table -->
      <table class="table table-striped grid">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="demo"></tbody>
      </table>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/3.0.6/isotope.pkgd.min.js" integrity="sha512-Zq2BOxyhvnRFXu0+WE6ojpZLOU2jdnqbrM1hmVdGzyeCa1DgM3X5Q4A/Is9xA1IkbUeDd7755dNNI/PzSf2Pew==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `\`<tr class="element-item ${name}">\``?

Comment: You can do it with `"<tr class='element-item " + name + "'>" +`. Anyway, I'd rather do it with template string.

Comment: Looks like a typo to me: in your code there is no closing double quote for the `class` attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mess up with this string concatanations, use helper functions and   `

```js
function createTr(name, age, email) {
    return `<tr class="element-item ${name}">
    <td>${age}</td>
    <td>${email}</td>
    </tr>`;
}
```